# Behavior of using \Z vs \z as Scanner delimiter

Tags: java, character-encoding, eof

[Edit] I found the answer, but I can't answer the question due to restrictions on new users. Either way, this is a known bug in Java.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8028387

I'm trying to read a file into a string in Java 6 on 64 bit ubuntu. Java is giving me the very strange result that with `"\\Z"` it reads the entire file, but with `"\\z"` it reads the entire string up to 1024 characters. I've read the Java 6 API for all the classes and I am at a loss.

Description of \Z and \z can be found at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt

What could be causing this strange behavior?

```
String fileString = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\\z").next();
String fileString2 = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
System.out.println("using Z : " + fileString2.length());
System.out.println("Using z "+ fileString.length());
```

Output:
using Z : 9720
Using z : 1024

Thanks!

Details about the file/java-version:

Running Ubuntu with java-6-openjdk-amd64 (tested also with oracle java6)
File is simple text file UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I've done it for you :-)

Comment: OK.  Since you have undone my edit ... you can improve your Question is as follows: 1) Remove *"Thanks"*.  The best way to express thanks is to upvote relevant answers and accept the best one.  2) Remove the *"First time poster ..."* stuff.  It is not part of your main question, and we can tell if you are first time poster anyway.  If you *particularly* want people to comment on your questions, then ask for comments in a comment.

Comment: You could also help people answer if you showed us what the input file looks like ... 'cos people are having problems reproducing it.  Note that the answer you accepted is only a theory.  I have my doubts that it is the real explanation, because if it is, it would be a simple Java bug, and simple Java bugs are rare in the wild.  (People tend to find them much earlier than this.)

Comment: Hmm ... what I meant was / is a simple bug in the standard Java claass library.

Comment: Thanks Stephen - I'll redo your edit. I didn't notice it was an edit of yours and just thought I somehow messed up submission of my question. My input were simple text files with UTF-8 encoding. The error was present in all files. For example a file consisting of only a's (no new lines/spaces etc.). I'll look more into the file and update my question. Thanks.

Comment: I implemented a while loop that prints the lengths of the tokens produced by the scanner with small '\\z', and they consistently are of size 1024, except for the last one which is of variable length.

Answer (score 8):

As [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation states

- `\z` The end of the input
- `\Z` The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any

I suspect that since Scanners buffer size is set to [1024](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#354),

```
354  private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // change to 1024;
```

Scanner reads this amount of characters and uses it as current input, so `\z` can be used here to represent its end, while `\Z` can't because it is not "final terminator" (there are more elements in entire input to read).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I guess I didn't parse the sentence "Z The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any" correctly. I need to google what "final Terminator" is. Thanks!!

Comment: @Pshemo ... that is a plausible explanation.  However, I don't see how such behaviour would be justified based on what the spec says.  Buffering should be transparent.

Comment: @StephenC That is why I said that is only my suspicion. I am also trying to figure it out in more details but without any luck so far :/

Comment: Yes, for now I was using Pattern/Matcher classes with some combinations of `multiline` flags, different length of strings, placing `\r` `\n` before and after 1024th character but can't reproduce this behavior. For now I can't do more but later will try to take deeper look how Scanner class uses delimiters.

Comment: @StephenC `Have you tried to reproduce it?` If you ware asking about reproducing original problem OP is having then I did it based on OP comment under (now deleted) Bohemian answer, where it is said that file is filled only with `a`. Code to reproduce this problem can look like http://ideone.com/pkrxuI.

Comment: @StephenC My first comment was about reproducing this behavior in different scenario, which could explain in more detail how it should work.

Comment: @StephenC So is this a bug in Java that we have come across :) http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8028387

Comment: This looks like this is not a bug but intended behavior. The devs have probably declared it as `won't fix`.